# react-native link @shoutem/ui

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I am having issues installing `@shouted/ui`. Seems like `react-native link` is not resolving the path correctly.

React Native is attempting to access `node_modules/@shoutem/ui/node_modules`
but there is no such folder, within the ui folder, which got me thinking it could be the new `node` version 7.x I was using. Downgrading didn't help.

Did anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 0):

We're working on this issue and it will be solved in the following version, which is coming tomorrow the latest. However, you can already use [@shoutem/ui](https://github.com/shoutem/ui) now, as these errors don't affect the usage of the library at all.

EDIT: Our toolkit has went through several updates now and it should be all working.